# How well does Teradata deal with Foreign Keys?

Tags: teradata

I'm starting a new project and one of the requirements is to use Teradata. I'm proficient in many different database systems but Teradata is fairly new to me.

On the client end they have removed all foreign keys from their database under the recommendations of "a consultant".

Every part of me cringes.

I'm using a new database instance so I'm not constrained by what they've already done on other databases. I haven't been explicitly told not to use foreign keys and my relation with the customer is such that they will at the very least hear me out. However, my decision and case should be well-informed.

Is there any intrinsic, technological reason that I should not use FKs in Teradata to maintain referential integrity based upon Teradata's design, performance, side-effects, etc...

Of note, I'm accessing Teradata using the .Net Data Provider v16 which only supports up to EF5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the new project is implementing a Data Warehouse there's a simple reason (and this is true for any DWH, not only Teradata): a DWH is not the same as an OLTP system.

Of course you still got Primary & Foreign Keys in the Logical data model, but maybe not implemented in the Physical model (although they are supported by Teradata). There are several reasons:

- Data is usually loaded in batches into a DWH and both PK & FKs must be validated by the loading process before Insert/Update/Delete. Otherwise you load 1,000,000 rows and there's a single row failing the constraints. Now you got a Rollback and an error message and try to find the bad data, good luck. But when all the validation is already done during load there's no reason to do the same checks a 2nd time within the database.
- Some tables in the DWH will be Slowly Changing Dimensions and there's no way to define a PK/FK on that usibg Standard SQL syntay, you need something like *TableA.column references TableB.column and TableA.Timestamp between TableB.ValidFrom and TableB.ValidTo* (it is possible when you create Temporal Table)
- Sometimes a table is recreated or reloaded from scratch, hard to do if there's a FK referencing it.
- Some PKs are never used for any access/join, so why implementing them physically, it's just a huge overhead in CPU/IO/storage.

Knowledge about PK/FK is important for the optimizer, so there's a so-called *Soft Foreign Key* (`REFERENCES WITH NO CHECK OPTION`), which is a kind of dummy: applied during optimization, but never actually checked by the DBMS (it's like telling the optimizer *trust me, it's correct*).

Comment: In this application, half will be of a more traditional usage - something a typical application would use MySql or MS Sql Server for. Would it make sense to go ahead and use FKs on those but not the other half which would be more DWH?

Comment: If you have a typical OLTP usage, i.e. small transactions on a few rows, you can go with Standard or Batch FKs, but never in a DWH.